# How to asynchronously send all the uploaded files at once in MVC Telerik Upload Control?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, telerik, telerik-mvc

I am using telerik file upload control for my MVC3 application. I am using its asynchronous feature to upload the files. 
Below is the code that I am using.

```
@(Html.Telerik().Upload()
        .Name("files")
        .ShowFileList(true)    
        .Multiple(true)                                    
        .Async(
                async => async
                .Save("Save", "MyController")
                .AutoUpload(false)
                .Remove("Remove", "MyController")                            
            )
    )

[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Save(IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files)
        {            
            foreach (var file in files)
            {
                // Some browsers send file names with full path. We only care about the file name.
                var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
                var destinationPath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data"), fileName);

                file.SaveAs(destinationPath);
            }
            return Content("");
        }
```

The above piece of code will generate two buttons viz. "Select" and "Upload files". After selecting 4 files and pressing "upload files" button, the telerik calls the action method 4 times asynchronously (which is bad). What I wanted was the method should be called only once and all the 4 files should be send to the method at once (as I am accepting list of files).

So, How can I achieve this in Html.Telerik().Upload() control?

Also, I will be showing this control in my Html.Telerik().Window(), So I will need to send uploaded data to my parent page. Any helps how to do this too?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As a suggestion, you might consider letting the files upload asynchronously if you are going to process them as a part of a form post with other values. I did this by using a hidden form field to associate an ID with the uploaded files and including that value in the onUpload(e) client event's e.data argument. This way you can validate the form while the files are saved off in a temp location and process the form post along with the files associated with your ID.

Otherwise if you absolutely want synchronous, it appears you should have no problem doing a multiple synchronous upload according to Telerik's documentation.

http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-mvc/telerik-ui-components-upload-synchronous-upload.html